# How to clear temp view cache in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does spark application clears the cache when I drop the temp view which was cached ?

I've added below snippet to give more details on the question.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_view_1 AS
    SELECT
        column1,
        column2
    FROM  Table1;
CACHE TABLE temp_view_1;

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_view_2 AS
    SELECT
    /*+ BROADCAST(b) */
        a.column1,
        a.column2
  FROM  Table2 a JOIN temp_view_1 b ON a.column1 = b.column1 ;


CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_view_3 AS
    SELECT
    /*+ BROADCAST(b) */
        a.column1,
        a.column2
  FROM  Table3 a JOIN temp_view_1 b ON a.column1 = b.column1 ;

DROP TABLE temp_view_1; -- Does this  statement clear the cache as well ? If not, how can I clear cache ?

SELECT
        a.column1,
        a.column2
  FROM  temp_view_2 a JOIN temp_view_3 b ON a.column1 = b.column1 ;
```

Question is, does statement like **DROP TABLE temp_view_1** clear the cache as well ? If not, how can I clear cache ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `DROP VIEW` for `%sql` and if it has been cached, the cache will be cleared. The manual states that and that would also be logical. No worries.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you mean by %sql. I've couple of questions: 1) If I had more than one VIEWs then Does DROP VIEW clear the cache for all the VIEWs ? 2) If I had more than one VIEWs how can I clear the cache for only specified VIEW

Comment: %sql is if in a Databricks note bpook, but it does not matter - disregard. You can also use spark.catalog.dropTempView("df"). 1) Only in the case of a dependent view. Need individual DROP VIEWs.  2) not sure i follow.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. You can ignore 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dropTempView` function.

you can find this function under [Catalog](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html) class.